# How do I use CAM::PDF to extract all pages?

Tags: perl, pdftotext, pdf-parsing

```
#!/perl/bin/perl -w
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;

$filename = "test.pdf";

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(2);
$text = CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
#$text =~ s/regex/modify/gi;
print $text;
```

With the code above I can extract pdf data into a text file, but I can only get one page.  I would like to get every single page within my pdf.

I know it is in the line containing

```
my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(2);
```

I am not to sure how to change it.  I have even tried (1..200) and it only give me the first page.  Is anyone familiar with using CAM::PDF??

Comment: Isn't the `getPageText($pagenum)` right method to use? And, btw, adding strict&warnings before posting code sample here is not right use of them, it does not help you at all. Your example code does not run.

Answer (score 4):

This works for what I need.

```
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;
$filename = "test.pdf";

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
for my $page (1..$pdf->numPages) {
my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree($page);
$text = CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
print $text;

}
```

The numPages function grabs the number of pages from the pdf.

Comment: Yep, that's the right solution. (I'm the author of CAM::PDF)

Comment: I get `Can't locate object method "render" via package "CAM::PDF::PageText" at`.